# pandas group data by year and give rank based on multiple(two) col

Tags: python, pandas

After several hours of research  I still cannot be able to group my data by year and give rank based on two cols such that there no ties in rank whenever values in first col are the same.

I can only be able to give rank based on two columns but I am unable to group the data first.
below is what i have done.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Ene_E/Desktop/Data/data.csv')
>>> cols = ['score1', 'score2']
>>> tups = data[cols].sort_values(cols, ascending=False).apply(tuple, 1)
>>> f, i = pd.factorize(tups)
>>> factorized = pd.Series(f + 1, tups.index)
>>> wellranked = data.assign(Rank=factorized)
>>> wellranked.to_csv('wellrank.csv')
```

below is example of my data

```
name        year       score1          score2
brand1       2015       2500            5
brand2       2015       2500            3
brand3       2015       1500            7
brand1       2016       3200            2
brand2       2016       3000            4
brand3       2016       2100            6
```

my code produces this

```
name        year       score1          score2     Rank
brand1       2015       2500              1       3            
brand2       2015       2500              2       4
brand3       2015       1500              3       6
brand1       2016       3200              1       1      
brand2       2016       3000              2       2
brand3       2016       2100              3       5
```

but i want it this way..

```
name        year       score1          score2     Rank
brand1       2015       2500              1        1           
brand2       2015       2500              2        2
brand3       2015       1500              3        3
brand1       2016       3200              1        2     
brand2       2016       3300              2        1
brand3       2016       2100              3        3
```

Comment: ur sample data and expected output has significant changes in score 2 values. what's the logic behind the change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) per `year`s:

```
cols = ['score1', 'score2']
tups = data[cols].sort_values(cols, ascending=False).apply(tuple, 1)

factorized = tups.groupby(data['year']).transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1)
wellranked = data.assign(Rank=factorized)
print (wellranked)
     name  year  score1  score2  Rank
0  brand1  2015    2500       5     1
1  brand2  2015    2500       3     2
2  brand3  2015    1500       7     3
3  brand1  2016    3200       2     1
4  brand2  2016    3000       4     2
5  brand3  2016    2100       6     3
```